Does $\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{z^k}{k!^s}$ only have negative real roots?
It might be complicated to decide whether or not a given entire function has only real zeros. So, I'll focus on special examples. It is known that the following function given by the infinite series,
$$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{z^k}{k!^2}$$
has infinitely many real zeros only (from Bessel function theory).

QUESTION. Fix an integer $s\geq3$. Can we say the same about the following entire functions?
$$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{z^k}{k!^s}.$$


what you claim in the post is not correct as $f(z)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{z^{2k}}{k!^2}$ has roots on the imaginary axis; $f(iz)=\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^k\frac{z^{2k}}{k!^2}$ has real zeroes

@Conrad: correct. I need to fix it.

Strictly speaking, the series you give initially is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k}/k!^2=I_0(2z^{1/2})$. It's a bit of a stretch to call that "a Bessel function" but it does have the advantage of localizing the zeros to the negative real axis. More generally, though, the series you're interested in is a generalized hypergeometric function: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!^s}={0}F{s-1}(;1,1,\ldots,1,z)$$
